# swift cannot convert value of type (_, _) -> _ to expected argument type '((_, CGFloat)) -> _

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I am using a library [URLEmbeddedView](https://github.com/marty-suzuki/URLEmbeddedView)

It defines following code in its library:

```
func addConstraints(with view: UIView, center: CGPoint, multiplier: CGFloat = 1) {
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addConstraints([
            (.centerX, center.x),
            (.centerY, center.y)
        ]
        .flatMap {
            .init(item: view,
                  attribute: $0,
                  relatedBy: .equal,
                  toItem: self,
                  attribute: $0,
                  multiplier: multiplier,
                  constant: $1)
        })
}
```

We are generating preview of link through the Library but following error is occurring :

> cannot convert value of type (_, _) -> _ to expected argument type
>   '((_, CGFloat)) -> _" at .flapMap line.

I am familiar with `Objective-C` but not with `Swift`. What will be the issue in the code?

[image]

Comment: Which iOS version are you using?

Comment: We are checking in iOS 10.1 @PGDev

Comment: On what line are you getting the issue?

Comment: @PGDev I have attached an image for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was also necessary to use Xcode version above 8.1.

I have used the same code as yours. Just applied the constraints to `view` and it works perfectly.

```
   view.addConstraints([
        (.centerX, center.x),
        (.centerY, center.y)
        ].flatMap {
            .init(item: view, attribute: $0, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: $0, multiplier: multiplier, constant: $1)
    })
```

There is no issue in the `flatMap` syntax. I have executed the code on `Xcode-9` as well as `Xcode-8` and it doesn't give me any error.

Just used the same code that I have written above and see if it compiles correctly.

Comment: self.view isn't necessarily the view that was passed in

Comment: Its just any view on which you want to apply the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong `addConstraints()` is being called.

You're calling `viewController.addConstraints()` when it appears you want to call `view.addConstraints()`

Change the second `addConstraints()` to `view.addConstraints()`

Comment: @BhargavSoni updated the answer. Confirmed it on my end